# How to implement Recycler View with multiple layout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, gridview, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a Recycler view like this:
[image]

at start, we have two different layout , first layout is a ViewPager 
and second layout is an ImageView and in following is gridView...
after scrolling gridView come up and other layouts should be invisible

how can do it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you do it:

- Use GridLayoutManager
- Define 3 types of view item (view pager, image view, normal) and implement [`getItemViewType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) method. Return correspond view type with it position.
- Implement `onCreateViewHolder` create the correspond `ViewHolder` with view type given.
- Finally set span size for each view type like:

Use `setSpanSizeLookup` method.

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {@Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch (mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
            case MyAdapter.TYPE_VIEW_PAGER:
                return 2;
            case MyAdapter.TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW:
                return 2;
            case MyAdaper.TYPE_NORMAL:
                return 1;
        }
    }
});
```